# There is no 'ok' button on the smtp connection manager editor

Tags: ssis

I am trying to edit send mail task in SSIS but unable to create a new SMTP connection manager. There is an absence of the button 'ok' on the editor screen. Does any one know the reason?

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: I am not sure how to attach a screen shot on this page.

Comment: @Yuchhttps://docs.google.com/document/d/1G6KvlnKp2bOhRP9jIDivVE4gL2Jfphfhbne1Rl3hx48/edit

Comment: Your link brings me to a blank document.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my questions. I put the screen shot on Google docs through this link if ithelps:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1G6KvlnKp2bOhRP9jIDivVE4gL2Jfphfhbne1Rl3hx48/edit

Comment: I've edited your question and posted the screen shot inline. This looks like a problem with your Windows UI settings. Everything is so huge. Strange as it may sound, is it possible that the buttons are pushed past the end of the dialog?

Comment: Thanks Yuck, I did not think that was the cause but when I try to set my screen to smallest display, I can see the button now. I used Windows 7 and always set to medium display. I kept thinking that is something wrong with my BI. Thanks heaps for your time helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this example [Send Mail Task in SSIS 2008](http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.co.uk/2010/07/send-mail-task-in-ssis-2008.html), when I add a new smtp connection I get the following

[image: smtp]

To attach a screen shot, print screen, paste / save into mspaint then use the image button to include a screen shot

[image: image button]